# Perfomance impact of Ruby freeze

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How are these different?

```
CONST = ["a","b"].freeze
```

and

```
CONST = ["a".freeze, "b".freeze]
```

I know that the first one freezes any modification to the array, but from a Rails point of view, if I am constantly loading this constant in my app, which is a better way to save some memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is, the first one:

```
CONST = ["a","b"].freeze
```

because if you freeze the array, you can't modify the array anyway.

Also, if you do this: `CONST = ["a".freeze, "b".freeze]`, it just means you are freezing those two elements of the array only. You will still be able to modify the `CONST` array and add items to it for example, which is not something that people usually want.

Also, with `CONST = ["a","b"].freeze`, the array is frozen, but the array items can still be modified (because they are still strings and hence mutable): `CONST[0] << 'something'` still works. So, if you really want to make the array frozen along with all of it's items frozen, then you would need to call `.freeze` on each item as well: `CONST = ["a".freeze, "b".freeze].freeze` which is very unusual in practice, according to my experience. But, it depends on your need, of course.

Comment: Thanks, Islam! On a side note, what is the point of using freeze on a constant? For eg:  we assign A = "hello" and whenever we call A, its object_id will be same. Even if its A = "hello".freeze, object_id is same everwhere. So what is the advantage of calling freeze on a string constant?

Comment: If you freeze `CONST` array, this way you can ensure that no one else can't modify this array in your codebase. This is useful when you have a constant array in a large codebase and no one else can accidentally modify the array in some other place of the codebase.

Comment: If you have a constant string or array that is being use in many places of your codebase, you would want to keep that constant as real constant and no one else should modify that in some other place of your codebase. By calling `.freeze` on it, you are ensuring that. Hope this helps. Let me know if you have any other question.

Comment: Look at this interesting Rails PR: https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/5bb1d4d288d019e276335465d0389fd2f5246bfd

Comment: Thank you so much Islam! Your explanation and  Rails PR made it much clearer. I was trying this out in irb and didn't find any change. So, this works only for ruby files on disk, like a Rails App?
Also, if you currently have a constant like A = "hello", making it A="hello".freeze will definitely give some performance boost? (Even minor)

Comment: Yes, you are right. You should freeze all the constant strings in your app.

Comment: You wrote *if you freeze the array, you can't modify the array anyway and none of it's items*. I am afraid that is not true. You cannot modify a frozen array, but you can still change the items inside. Check: `CONST = ["a","b"].freeze ; CONST[0] << 'foo' ; CONST` Therefore you need to do both: freeze the array and freeze each element in the array.

Comment: Ah, right. You can change the items. `CONST[0] = 'c'` actually fails that's what I tested. But, this works: `CONST[0] << 'c'`. Will update the answer. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: But, do we usually do that in practice? I always just freeze the array itself, never tried freezing each item in the array like that. Today I Learned :)